# Shiny img() function , how do I get image to appear?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to using Shiny but my img() function is not working. I have placed it in a directory call `www` in the folder that contains my `app.R` file and tried using both .jpg and .png but the image does not appear.

The code for my Shiny app is

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Customers"),

 sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
  h1("Choose Dataset"),
  br(),
  br(),
  br(),
  br(),
  br(),

  img(scr = "Logo.jpg", height = 100, width = 150)),


mainPanel(
  h1("Results"),
  p("The results are as follows")
    )
 )
)
# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output) {

}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I have also tried the other answers that suggest using `runApp` that has not worked either.

Can anyone help as to why the image does not want to appear?

I am now receving the following errors:

```
Warning in pngfun(filename = filename, width = width, height = height, res = res,  :
  unable to allocate bitmap
Warning in pngfun(filename = filename, width = width, height = height, res = res,  :
  opening device failed
Warning: Error in pngfun: unable to start png() device
  [No stack trace available]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have a tiny typo (scr instead of src)... Try this:

```
img(src = "Logo.jpg", height = 100, width = 150))
```

It should work if Logo.jpg is in www/

Comment: Question mark appears now which seems like progress. My logo is in my_app/www

Comment: And my my app is in my_app/app.R. This should work no?

Comment: @geds133 Yes, it should. Is the file name/extension correct?

Comment: img(src = "Logo.jpg", height = 100, width = 150))

UserRedirects\gchurch\Documents\my_app\www\Logo